# Avoiding multiples of $p$

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, prime-numbers, additive-combinatorics

Let $p$ be a prime number and $P=\{1,2,...,p-1\}$

In how many ways we can sum *all* the elements of $P$ in such a way that we will reach a multiple of $p$
only when we sum the last summand?

For example let $p=7$ .
Clearly, $1+2+3+4+5+6$ is such a sum   (In fact there exist $408$ such sums)
  but $2+3+5+4+1+6$ is not, because already $2+3+5+4=2\cdot7$.

We can see after a little investigation that if the total number of sums is $f(p)$,then

$\frac{(p-1)!}{p-2}\leq f(p)\leq (p-1)!$ (equality holds iff $p=3$)

Is it possible to improve this (to find asymptotic bounds or -even better- something precise)?
Thanks in advance!
**EDIT** : It is possible to prove in an elementary way that for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$,  $\phi(n)\mid f(n)$
($\phi(n)$ is Euler's function)

Comment: Looks like the Bonferroni inequalities should give an asymptotic of $(\frac{1}{e}+o(1)) (p-1)!$.

Comment: @TerryTao How?Could you be more specific?

Comment: The asymptotic above is also what one expects using the naive probabilistic heuristic that the probability of getting a multiple of $p$ for the $k^{th}$ sum is $\frac{1}{p}$ and each event is independent.

Comment: Have you tried computing it for the first few primes and then consulting the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences?

Comment: There's no reason to restrict attention to primes here as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson OEIS does not tell anything,if my calculations are correct.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan actually there is. if we consider the case for composite $n$ we may find less desirable sums.Let $n=15$.   $15|1+2+3+4+5= \frac{5(5+1)}{2}$.I expect the best case for primes because the smallest tringular number they divide is $1+2+\cdots +p-1$.I use primes to avoid  any trivial case (such as even numbers $n$.They never divide  $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ )I can imagine that if this is solved for primes, it could be easy to apply the idea on all natural numbers.

Comment: @Konstantinos: I don't see the relevance of triangular numbers. You're looking at all possible orders of the sum, and among those only a few will start with the first few numbers.

Comment: Here are my counts of such permutations for $p=1,2,\dots, 12$ (ignoring the requirement of p being prime):
1, 1, 2, 4, 16, 56, 408, 2376, 19920, 156096, 1711680, 16851072.
Also, if we include element $p$ into permutations, the counts become: 1, 1, 2, 12, 48, 280, 2040, 16632, 139440, 1404864, 15405120 which for prime $p$ are just the previous counts times $(p-2)$.

Comment: @Qiaochu - first comment: It is quite naive to suppose those events are independent since if one is divisible by $p$, the next isn't. However, if we use Max's observation that adding $p$ to the set $P$ is an equivalent problem, it looks more natural.

Comment: I took a liberty to add my counts to OEIS as http://oeis.org/A232664 and http://oeis.org/A232663 respectively.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev thank you for the help-computation.

Comment: A slightly better bound for $p\geq 7$, but not helpful in finding asymptotic: $(p-1)(2(p-3)+(p-5)(p-4))(p-5)!\leq f(p)\leq (p-1)(2(p-3)+(p-5)(p-4))(p-4)!$

Comment: Something obvious, yet might gain utility from being mentioned: Consider the vector of partial sums mod p. If there are k unique entries (each such occurs exactly once) in that vector, then k of the p-1 rotations of that permutation will be desired permutations.  Perhaps the expected value of k will be nice to calculate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments above, the number of permutations of elements $1,2,\dots,p$ (i.e., including $p$) is just by factor of $p-2$ larger than the amount in question (in fact, this is true for any odd $p$). Such permutations are now counted in http://oeis.org/A232663

Here is an explicit formula for the number of such permutations for a prime $p$, which I got by playing with inclusion-exclusion:

$$\sum_{A\in M_p} (-1)^{m+n}\cdot \frac{1}{n!} \cdot p^{n-\mathrm{rank}(A)} \cdot \prod_{j=1}^n (c_j-1)! \cdot \prod_{i=1}^m \binom{r_i}{a_{i1}, \dots, a_{in}},$$

where:

- $M_p$ is the set of matrices with nonnegative integer entries that sum up to $p$, with no zero rows or columns. Size of $M_p$ is given by http://oeis.org/A120733
- $A=(a_{ij})$ is a matrix of size $m\times n$ (i.e., $m$ and $n$ are respectively the number of rows and columns in $A$);
- $c_j = \sum_{i=1}^m a_{ij}$ is the sum of $j$-th column of matrix $A$;
- $r_i = \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}$ is the sum of $i$-th row of matrix $A$;
- matrix rank is computed over $\mathrm{GF}(p)$.

The formula may not be so useful due to its complexity but it's still a nice one. But the same reason I do not post here its derivation as it would take at least a couple of pages.

The formula has been numerically tested for $p=5$ and $p=7$.

Comment: We call a sum to be primitive of size $k$ (denote this by $S_k=a_1+a_2+⋯+a_k$) if: $S_k=0modp$ and $a_1+⋯+a_i≠0modp$ where $i<k$ (all the $a_k$ are different and $\leq p−1$).Then the number we want is $N(S_{p−1})=(p−1)!−N(S_2)⋅(p−3)!−⋯−N(S_{p−2})\cdot 1$ where $N(S_i)$ denotes the number of primitive sums of sike $i$ .But this is far away from giving some information also. But, thank for the support anyway